# Who sends QEvent::LocaleChange?

Tags: c++, qt

I familiarized myself with the perils of locales and translations in Qt. The hardest thing for me to realize actually was the *order* how localization works:

1. The locale (as in `QLocale`) can change spontaneously,
2. The language (as in `QTranslator`) may change *in response* to the locale change.

So for Qt this means that installing/removing `QTranslators` will cause an event of type `QEvent::LanguageChange` to be posted to the `QApplication` instance, which will in turn propagate it through all the widgets.

From the `QApplication` source I learnt that events of type `QEvent::LocaleChange` are also propagated through all the widgets. This seems reasonable to me.

However, I could not find a single place in the Qt sources where an event of that type is actually *posted*. How and especially where does Qt react to locale changes of the underlying operating system?

How do I change the application's locale? The obvious way seems to be setting the default locale using `QLocale::setDefault()` and then manually post the `QEvent::LocaleChange` to the `QApplication` instance...